# Haskell Parsec functionality

Tags: haskell, csv, parsec

Ive been working with this page 
http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html
and I'm trying to get a CSV file parser working, but I noticed that

```
parse csvFile "(stdin)" str
```

always returns a

```
Right [["s","o"],["h","i"]]
```

Is there a way to make parse, work where it returns just the array of arrays which I can use later in my code?

eg code:

```
main = mainLoop []

mainLoop :: [[String]] -> IO ()
mainLoop db = do
     answer <- getLine
     case words answer of
        ("load":x) -> do
                str <- readFile (head x)
                mainLoop $ parseCSV str
        ("quit":_) -> return ()
        ("help":_) -> do 
                        putStrLn "This is your help"
                        mainLoop db
        otherwise  -> putStrLn "Not sure what you want me to do! :(" >> mainLoop db

csvFile = endBy line eol
line = sepBy cell (char ',')
cell = many (noneOf ",\n")
eol = char '\n'

parseCSV :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
parseCSV input = parse csvFile "(unknown)" input
```

Thank you

Comment: But then how will you do error handling? Are you OK with having your program crash if the input can't be parsed?

Comment: You know you can convert that value `Right [[...], [...]]` into the list of lists: `[ [...], [...] ]` - don't you?  You can use the [either](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:either) funciton, if you want `either (error . show) id (parseCSV input)`

Answer (score 2):

The `Right ...` simply means that the operation could have had an error. You can deal with this using a `case` statement:

```
case parse csvFile "(stdin)" str of
  Left  err -> handle err
  Right res -> doStuff res
```

The whole `Either` design pattern lets you handle arbitrary errors in your code in a nice way. You can deal with the error however you like, and you don't have to worry about run-time exceptions, which Haskellers hate.

As Thomas helpfully pointed out in the comments, you can also use the `either` function to do the same thing as the case statement.

Comment: I did try using something like that, but I couldn't get it to work for some reason. I used it in my code case for load, so there was a case switch within a case switch. and for the Right res -> mainLoop res. This didnt work.

Comment: It sounds like you made some sort of syntax error with the case statements. What was the error message, exactly?

Comment: I cant remember now and I moved on with the code, thank you though :)